# Transforming Numeric into Date

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

My data looks in this format

```
ID     Date       Order
1   12/12/2015      1
1   12/13/2015      2
1   12/14/2015      3
1   12/15/2015      4
2   12/12/2015      1
2   12/13/2015      2
2   12/14/2015      3
2   12/15/2015      4
```

Now, I'm transforming the data into wide format using tidyr. So the new data looks like this.

```
ID   Date_1     Date_2       Date_3    Date_4
1  12/12/2015 12/13/2015  12/14/2015 12/15/2015
2  12/12/2015 12/13/2015  12/14/2015 12/15/2015
```

The issue that I'm having is  while transformation, Date_1, Date_4 is becoming numeric. And when I try to convert them to character using the following code, I'm get the following error.

```
df[, 2:5] <- lapply(df[,2:5], as.Date)
```

Error:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

My question is how to convert the numeric data into date format.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to convert the single column to date before you do the transformation.  You just need to set the format, as shown below.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thanks for your comments. But I'm doing exactly the same thing. Still I'm getting numbers rather than date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use the correct `format` to convert it to `Date` class.

```
df[2:5] <- lapply(df[2:5], as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df
#  ID     Date_1     Date_2     Date_3     Date_4
#1  1 2015-12-12 2015-12-13 2015-12-14 2015-12-15
#2  2 2015-12-12 2015-12-13 2015-12-14 2015-12-15
```

If the "Date" columns were already in the format `"%Y-%m-%d"`, then we don't have to specify the format.

---

It is not clear how we got a numeric "Date" columns while reshaping

```
library(tidyr)
OrigDf %>% 
     mutate(Order = paste0("Date", Order)) %>% 
     spread(Order, Date)
#  ID      Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
#1  1 12/12/2015 12/13/2015 12/14/2015 12/15/2015
#2  2 12/12/2015 12/13/2015 12/14/2015 12/15/2015
```

NOTE: Even if is an `factor` column, the above output remains the same.

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, Date_1 = c("12/12/2015", "12/12/2015"
), Date_2 = c("12/13/2015", "12/13/2015"), Date_3 = c("12/14/2015", 
"12/14/2015"), Date_4 = c("12/15/2015", "12/15/2015")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date_1", "Date_2", "Date_3", "Date_4"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))


Origdf <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
 Date = c("12/12/2015", 
 "12/13/2015", "12/14/2015", "12/15/2015", "12/12/2015", "12/13/2015", 
 "12/14/2015", "12/15/2015"), Order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Order"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```